# Function I should use between Checkbox and Button on Wix

Tags: javascript, velo

As title, I working on a simple page on Wix, and it is about users have to click on the checkbox to agree the term of use of the site  before they press "continue" button. I am currently stuck, and the code I have is as follows Please let me if there is any solution to it.

```
$w.onReady(function(){

let isChecked = $w("#checkbox1").checked; 
let isRequired= $w('#checkbox1').required; // true

if(isChecked === false)
{
    $w('#button1').disable;
}else{
    $w("#button1").enable;
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Velo, [onReady](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/onready) only fires on the initial page load, so if a user interacts with the checkbox, you need to handle that with an [onClick event listener](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/checkbox/onclick). Additionally, [enable](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/button/enable) and [disable](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/button/disable) are functions. You may want to disable the button by default, but then you will need some code like this to handle the checkbox interaction.

```
$w("#checkbox1").onClick(function () {
    if ($w("#checkbox1").checked) {
        $w('#button1').enable();
    } else {
        $w('#button1').disable();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an EventListener to the checkbox so that the isChecked variable will update when the checkbox value changes.

I'm not too familiar with JQuery but in vanillaJS you can use something like.

```
const checkbox = document.getElementByID('checkbox1');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', ($event) => {
  isChecked = $event.target.checked;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disabled continue button by default on page load and add `click` event listener to catch checkbox click. You should try below code.

```js
$w.onReady(function(){
$w('#button1').disable;

let isChecked = $w("#checkbox1").checked; 
let isRequired= $w('#checkbox1').required; // true

$("#checkbox1").click(function(){
  $w('#button1').disable;
});
```